# C++ template meta-programming, number of member variables?

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Is it possible in C++ to determine number of variables/fields in the generic class?
for example

```
// suppose I need metaclass number_members determines number of members

struct example { int i, j; };
assert(number_members<example>::value==2);
```

I looked through mpl but could not find implementation.

thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to know how many without knowing what they are?

Comment: I know how to work with types, I am not familiar with other aspects and features of template meta-programming such as this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. C++ does not provide general introspection into structures.

You can try a C[++0x `std::tuple`](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#std-tuple), which has some of the features of a general POD `struct`. Or, try to roll your own from the [Boost MPL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html) library. That would be a bit advanced if you're just getting started with C++.

Comment: Also look at Boost.Fusion while you are at it. It's a good way to mix templates and runtime code. I have personally use `boost::fusion::map` as a skeleton for `struct` / `class` when I needed simili-reflection.

Answer (score 1):

No. Unfortunately, C++ does not have that kind of introspection builtin. However, with some additional preprocessing such as [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/products)'s [Meta Object Compiler (moc)](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/moc.html), you can achieve something similar... the [QMetaObject](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qmetaobject.html) class provides a [propertyCount()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qmetaobject.html#propertyCount); however, your class would need to inherit from [QObject](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qobject.html), use the Q_OBJECT macro, and register the properties for all that to work... so, in short, it's not automatic.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that directly. The obvious question then, is what you're trying to accomplish -- chances are that you can do what you need to, but the way to do it may be rather different.

Comment: actually, not really trying to do anything specific.
Just thought how I could do it and realizing I do not know how, decided to ask a question. just trying to learn additional aspects.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with restrictions. You can find my implementation at [mattkretz/virtools](https://github.com/mattkretz/virtools/blob/master/struct_reflect.h). It requires C++20, because it uses concepts. In principle, you can rewrite it using `enable_if` and thus make it work with C++17. [Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/sp9toG).

The main idea here is to restrict the set of types that can be inspected to aggregates with non-static data members either in a single base class or only in the derived class (but still allowing empty base classes). This is the same restriction structured bindings imposes. Then you know whether a type `T` has e.g. 3 (or more) members if `T{anything_but_base_of<T>(), anything_but_base_of<T>(), anything_but_base_of<T>()}` is a valid expression (i.e. no substitution failure). Where `anything_but_base_of` is:

```cpp
template <class Struct> struct anything_but_base_of {
  template <class T>
  requires(!std::is_base_of_v<T, Struct>)
  operator T();
};
```

Since aggregate initialization allows to specify fewer initializers than the aggregate has members one has to test starting from an upper bound and then recurse down to 0 until a possible aggregate initialization is found. The destructuring test my implementation uses is actually not a SFINAE condition, but rather produces a hard error. So you can just as well remove that code, making the implementation:

```cpp
namespace detail {
template <class Struct> struct any_empty_base_of {
  template <class T>
  requires(std::is_base_of_v<T, Struct> && std::is_empty_v<T>)
  operator T();
};

template <class T, size_t... Indexes>
concept brace_constructible =
   requires { T{((void)Indexes, anything_but_base_of<T>())...}; } 
|| requires { T{any_empty_base_of<T>(), ((void)Indexes, anything_but_base_of<T>())...}; }
|| requires { T{any_empty_base_of<T>(), any_empty_base_of<T>(), ((void)Indexes, anything_but_base_of<T>())...}; }
|| requires { T{any_empty_base_of<T>(), any_empty_base_of<T>(), any_empty_base_of<T>(), ((void)Indexes, anything_but_base_of<T>())...}; };

template <class T, size_t... Indexes>
requires brace_constructible<T, Indexes...>
constexpr size_t struct_size(std::index_sequence<Indexes...>)
{
  return sizeof...(Indexes);
}

template <class T>
requires requires { T{}; }
constexpr size_t struct_size(std::index_sequence<>)
{
  static_assert(std::is_empty_v<T>,
                "Increase MaxSize on your struct_size call. (Or you found a bug)");
  return 0;
}

template <class T, size_t I0, size_t... Indexes>
requires(!brace_constructible<T, I0, Indexes...>)
constexpr size_t struct_size(std::index_sequence<I0, Indexes...>)
{
  // recurse with one less initializer
  return struct_size<T>(std::index_sequence<Indexes...>());
}
} // namespace detail
```

Finally, we need a sensible upper bound to start from. The correct upper bound would be `sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT`, for the case of a bitfield where each non-static data member occupies a single bit and the whole struct contains no padding. Considering the compile time cost of using the correct upper bound, I settled on a more sensible heuristic of simply `sizeof(T)`:

```cpp
template <typename T, size_t MaxSize = sizeof(T)>
constexpr inline std::size_t struct_size =
    detail::struct_size<T>(std::make_index_sequence<MaxSize>());
```

Comment: Can't aggregates have bitfields? The upper bound might need to be higher.

Comment: You're right, thanks for the hint. The use of bitfields smaller than `CHAR_BIT` would break the heuristic I used. `sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT` would be the correct upper bound. I will add it to the documentation of `vir::struct_size` and amend my answer accordingly.